# OVN Cluster Health Command

Tags: openstack, openvswitch, openstack-neutron, kolla-ansible, ovn

Is there any command-line tool for the OVN Cluster Health check? Or each of its components? and a command or commands which gives stats about the cluster.

For example, without a functional test, I want to know if everything works properly in our OVN Cluster which has deployed with Kolla-Ansible.

All OVSDBs and OVN-NB-DBs and OVN-SB-DBs are healthy or not?, all Daemons are healthy or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found these commands may be helpful

```
ovs-appctl -t /var/run/ovn/ovnnb_db.ctl cluster/status OVN_Northbound
ovs-appctl -t /var/run/ovn/ovnsb_db.ctl cluster/status OVN_Southbound
```

and these commands but not very helpful

```
/usr/share/ovn/scripts/ovn-ctl  status_ovnnb
/usr/share/ovn/scripts/ovn-ctl  status_ovnsb
```